# How to download multiple files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Scenario: there are multiple folders and many files stored in storage bucket that is accessible by project team members. Instead of downloading individual files one at a time (which is very slow and time consuming), is there a way to download entire folders? Or at least multiple files at once? Is this possible without having to use one of the command consoles? Some of the team members are not tech savvy and need to access these files as simple as possible. Thank you for any help!

Comment: How are they downloading them? Through the UI?

Comment: Incredible that such a basic option is not available as of 2020. Just got here because I wanted to download a whole folder at once, but couldn't...  Looks like the gsutils option is the only option.

Comment: has anyone else noticed that the "copy code" from the cloud console doesn't work? If you select multiple files, and try to download using the UI, it pops up with a snippet of gsutil commands you are supposed to use to be able to download those specific files, but when you copy and paste into cloud console, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

I would suggest downloading the files with `gsutil`. However if you have a large number of files to transfer you might want to use the gsutil `-m` option, to perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy:

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://your-bucket .
```

The time reduction for downloading the files can be quite significant. See this [Cloud Storage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) for complete information on the GCS `cp` command.

> If you want to copy into a particular directory, note that the directory must exist first, as `gsutils` won't create it automatically. (e.g: `mkdir my-bucket-local-copy && gsutil -m cp -r gs://your-bucket my-bucket-local-copy`)

Comment: When i did so, the command stopped at a file and didn't complete.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend they use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). GCS's API deals with only one object at a time. However, its command-line utility, `gsutil`, is more than happy to download a bunch of objects in parallel, though. Downloading an entire GCS "folder" with gsutil is pretty simple:

```
$> gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/remoteDirectory localDirectory
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do this via the python API, for just the content? I've discovered the get_media (alt=media in the REST API) function, but it's time consuming to loop over thousands of files. It would be really cool to just be able to get everything under a certain prefix, all at once.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Looping over the results of a list call is exactly what `gsutil` does, except it uses multiple threads.

Answer (score 4):

To download files to local machine need to:

1. install [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) to local machine
2. run *Google Cloud SDK Shell*
3. run the command like this (example, for Windows-platform):

```sh
gsutil -m cp -r gs://source_folder_path "%userprofile%/Downloads"
```

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil rsync -d -r  gs://bucketName .`
works for me