# Firebase Storage download to computer

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, firebase-storage

So I am trying to figure out how to download an array of images to a users computer. I have been storing everything through calling my server as I feel more secure using firebase on the server. So on click of a button on the client I can get a return of an array of the images in my firebase storage bucket.

Button click -> call server -> get a return of the array of urls from firebase

Now is there a way to download these to the users computer? Prompt them to choose a file path or download them directly?

I know I can do a single download auto by this:

```
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", url).attr("download", "img.png").appendTo("body");
a[0].click();
a.remove();
```

I have tested a single url download that auto downloads on the button click, but I dont feel like I should have to loop through the array one at a time to download all nor do I know if this would work. I would assume it would since a single url works.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to download multiple files in one request from Firebase Storage. If you want to allow downloading of multiple files, you'll have to store them in a single (say zip) file and use the approach you already do today for downloading that file.

Alternatively you can use the Google Cloud Storage API to download a bunch of files. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137053/how-to-download-multiple-files-in-google-cloud-storage) for more on that, but be aware the the Google Cloud Storage API is meant for use on an app server and not directly in your web page.